# should not the second code output just like the first

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does the second code give different output than the first one ?

1. Using a for loop:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 2, 7, 3, 8, 2]
uniques = []
for item in my_list:
    if item not in uniques:
        uniques.append(item)
print(uniques)
```

Output:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

2. Using list comprehension:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 2, 7, 3, 8, 2]
uniques = []
uniques = [item for item in my_list if item not in uniques]
print(uniques)
```

Output:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 2, 7, 3, 8, 2]
```

Comment: No, *absolutely not*. Why would it? `uniques = []` is *always empty* in the second piece of code. In the first, you add items one by one to that list.

Comment: As an aside, you should never use the algorithm in the first one. It is quadratic time. Use an auxiliary set object to keep track of already seen objects.  Or if you are on Python 3.7+, where `dict` objects maintain insertion order, you can be cute and use `list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))`

Comment: `list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))` works because dictionaries can only have every key once. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @Programmer yes?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `print(dict.fromkeys(["a", "a", "b", "b"]))` prints `{'a': None, 'b': None}` …

Comment: Just use set on the list, no need of looping.

Comment: @Programmer um OK? I'm not sure what the point you are trying to make is here...

Comment: @dswamy well, the assumption being that the OP wants to maintain the order (first seen). If not, yes, you could just do `set(my_list)` and if you needed a list in the end, `list(set(my_list))`

Answer (score 6):

The expression `[item for item in my_list if item not in uniques]` computes a new list based on the comprehension all at once. It then assigns the result to the name `uniques`. During the time the comprehension is running, `uniques` is an empty list, so the test `if item not in uniques` always returns `True`.

In the first version, `uniques` is referencing a list that is being actively updated, so it is able to meaningfully check for items already in the list.

As an aside, this is a very inefficient way to check for duplicates, because every time you write `if item not in uniques:`, the entire list is checked in linear time. A better alternative would be to use a `set`, which does fixed-time lookups using a hash-table.